# How to save and return cookies to the web service?

Tags: android

I'm using ksoap2 for web service method calls. I used `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar` and was able to retrieve header values from the web service response. I would like to save any returned cookies and return them with subsequent calls to the web service.

[I retrieved the header using the following code:](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/Cookies)

> SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
>
> envelope.dotNet = true;
>
> ```
>   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
>
>   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
>
>   List headerList = androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, null);
>
>   for (Object header : headerList) {
>       HeaderProperty headerProperty = (HeaderProperty) header;
>       String headerKey = headerProperty.getKey();
>       String headerValue = headerProperty.getValue();     
>   }
> ```

I tried to save it in SharedPreferences, but was unsuccessful. How cold I do this? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I went wrong when I tried to read the values from SharedPreference and so now I'm being able to save the header contents. But now a new exception arised :java.io.IOException: Content-Length underflow. How to solve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue solved.

To save the header contents:

> ```
>           Editor sharedPreferenceEditor = preferences.edit();
>
>           List headerList = androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, null);
>
>           for (Object header : headerList) {
>               HeaderProperty headerProperty = (HeaderProperty) header;
>               String headerKey = headerProperty.getKey();
>               String headerValue = headerProperty.getValue();
>
>               System.out.println(headerKey +" : " + headerValue);
>               sharedPreferenceEditor.putString(headerKey, headerValue);
>
>           }
>
>           sharedPreferenceEditor.commit();
> ```

To set the cookie on request:

> HeaderProperty headerPropertyObj = new
>   HeaderProperty("cookie",
>   preferences.getString("set-cookie",
>   ""));
>
> headerList.add(headerPropertyObj);
>
> androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,
>   envelope, headerList);

Comment: The headerList is `List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<>();` for reference.