# how do I retrieve the session token from httpResponse?

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpresponse

I am having a api which describes as follow:

Given a typical HTML form as follows:

```
 <form method="post" action="/api">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />
      <input type="hidden" name="username" value="testuser" />
      <input type="hidden" name="password" value="123" />
 </form>
```

When the HTML form above is submitted, the following shows an example of how
the information can be sent using HTTP protocol:

```
 POST /api HTTP/1.0
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Content-Length: 43
 action=login&username=testuser&password=123
```

The system will send back a reply which looks like the following:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
{ 'session_token':'a1234aa334567432bccdd001f123450abcedfa0b' }
```

Can anyone guide me to how am I suppose to retrieve the session token from the post response using android java?

EDIT: (here's some of my code to send and retrieve the request and response.)

```
  HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("url of server");
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","testuser" ));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234567" ));
        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
        HttpResponse response = getResponse(httpost);

public HttpResponse getResponse(HttpPost httpPost) throws Exception {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: this :: `http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/` will help you

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381491/how-to-save-and-return-cookies-to-the-web-service

Answer (score 0):

I am novice at Android API but would like to suggest the following:

**Option1**:
`Header[] headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();`

**Option2**:
`Header[] headers = httpResponse.getHeaders( "session_token_name_here" );`

Iterate headers array to find the required header, say `session_token`.